# CSS Table columns width: fixed - dynamic(30%) - dynamic(70%) - fixed

Tags: html, css

I managed to obtain this kind of table layout:

fixed - dynamic(50%) - dynamic(50%) - fixed

http://jsfiddle.net/ihtus/ksucU/

[image]

But how do I get this kind? fixed - dynamic(30%) - dynamic(70%) - fixed

[image]

Here's my CSS:

```
table {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:200px;">
        200px width - content
      </td>
      <td width="30%">
        dynamic width - content
      </td>
      <td width="70%">
        dynamic width - content
      </td>
      <td style="width:100px;">
         100px width - content
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

table {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7dSpr/

Comment: but why if not using "table-layout:fixed;" => everything breaks?

Comment: It is because `table-layout` by default is set to `auto` which means it will be as wide as the widest unbreakable content in the cells. `fixed` will take into consideration your width settings in the css. Note that not everything breaks, the percentage widths in the middle two columns will continue to be 30% and 70%.

Comment: will continue to be 30% and 70% from what width? from total table width? not from "w" width?

Comment: 30% and 70% of what ever is left after the two `td` elements on the left and right have expanded to fit the non-breakable content inside of them. In total the table will be 100% of the page including the default margins and padding.

Answer (score 2):

The general approach is the same as the one Monkieboy used, but you should avoid inline styles. ( by that I mean writing `style="someting"` ) in your html file. You should use classes and CSS instead.

First give the td a class like this `<td class="thin-column">text here</td>`,
then in your CSS use that to apply styles: `.thin-column:{ width: 30% }`

Comment: +1 - that is correct, I just did not want to write too much to illustrate a point.